# How to handle a selected item of LongListMultiSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to be able:

- to open a mail when the user taps on one item.
- and delete multiple emails when the user selects multiple emails

So I choosed `LongListMultiSelector`.

In built in `LongListSelector`, I handle the `SelectionChanged` event like this:

```
private void mails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = mailsLongListSelector.SelectedItem as Mail;

    if (selectedItem == null)
        return;
    ...
    mailsLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

I want exactly like that functionality in wptoolkit's `LongListMultiSelector`. like when you select an email to open and read it.

**LongListMultiSelector**'s `SelectionChanged` occurs when you tap left side of an item and checkboxes appear. this is not what I want.

**The Question is:**
How can I perform something when the user taps on one item of **LongListMultiSelector**? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. If this is your LongListSelector

```
<tkit:LongListMultiSelector Name="longlist" SelectionChanged="longlist_SelectionChanged">
    <tkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="32" Tap="TextBlock_Tap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </tkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</tkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

and it has an itemtemplate, you can detect a tap on item.

```
private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var itemTapped = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Book;
}
```

and still have a selection changed

```
private void longlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Hah, sometimes our mind goes too far. I have a trouble for an hour thinking how to handle this. what a stupid I am :\ ... thanks igrali

Comment: Firstly TextBlock_Tap event occurs, but after it doesn't work, because longlist_SelectionChanged event handles all the actions. How can i fix that?

Comment: The problem if at least one item is selected, then textblockTap event doesn't handle - longlist_SelectionChanged event handles everything.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are using LongListMultiSelector, the SelectionChanged event is fired when item is added or removed. If you want to perform the action regardless item is added/removed, I've managed to do it like this (for a simple string):

```
private void longlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = String.Empty;
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as string;
    else selectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as string;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem); // do your work
}
```

It should run while items are selected separately by tapping, but this method will have problems when more items are added/removed at the same time - if you need it, then you should handle this also.