# How do I handle a selected item of LongListMultiSelector?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have list of items in LongListMultiSelector - how to handle a selected item?

My LongListMultiSelector xaml:

```
<tkit:LongListMultiSelector Name="longlist" SelectionChanged="longlist_SelectionChanged">
    <tkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="32" Tap="TextBlock_Tap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </tkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</tkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

TextBlock tap event handler code:

```
private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var itemTapped = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Book;
}
```

LongListMultiSelector SelectionChanged event handler code:

```
private void longlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I found part of solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478744/how-to-handle-a-selected-item-of-longlistmultiselector), however, The problem if at least one item is selected, then textblockTap event doesn't handle - longlist_SelectionChanged event handles everything. How can i fix that?

Comment: do you wanna know the text of the selected item ?

Comment: Yes, everytime when I tapped

Comment: okay refer the answer

Comment: You want to use both: Tap and SelectionCHanged?

Comment: Either one is also Ok

Comment: The problem if at least one item is selected, then textblockTap event doesn't handle

Comment: Have you tried with SelectionChanged (without tap) and at the end of the event set `longlist.SelectedItem = null;`? (Also Begin your event with `if (longlist.SelectedItem == null) return;`)

Comment: There is no property SelectedItem

Comment: @NurzhanAitbayev Sorry for confusion - you are right, there is no SelectedItem (I haven't used LLMS before). I've checked how it works and maybe my answer will help you a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are using `LongListMultiSelector`, the `SelectionChanged` event is fired when item is added or removed. If you want to perform the action regardless item is added/removed, I've managed to do it like this (for a simle string):

```
private void longlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = String.Empty;
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as string;
    else selectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as string;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem); // do your work
}
```

It should run while items are selected separately by tapping, but this method will have problems when more items are added/removed at the same time - if you need it, then you should handle this also.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML DataTemplate.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="listItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,4">
            <TextBlock Tap="textblockTap" Margin="0,-7,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In your CS page;

```
    private void textblockTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var file = (TextBlock)sender;
            var ContentFile = (string)file.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(ContentFile);
    }
```

This example will show you the text of the selected item in the MessageBox.

Comment: The problem if at least one item is selected, then textblockTap event doesn't handle

Comment: Sorry i can't get you. Do you want to select more number of items ?